# Search and Replace in a file using arraylist, Java

Tags: java, arrays, search, replace

I wrote the below part of the code but I couldn't bind the arraylist with search and replace
so my csv file is as like below
1/1/1;7/6/1
1/1/2;7/7/1

I want to search the file 1.cfg for 1/1/1 and change it to 7/6/1 and 1/1/2 change to 7/7/1 and it goes so on.

Thank you all in advance

**It's now only printing in a new file only the last line of the old File**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ChangeConfiguration {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         try{
              // Open the file that is the first 
              // command line parameter
              FileInputStream degistirilecek = new FileInputStream("c:/Config_Changer.csv");
              FileInputStream config = new FileInputStream("c:/1.cfg");
              // Get the object of DataInputStream
              DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(config);
              DataInputStream degistir = new DataInputStream(degistirilecek);
              BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
              BufferedReader brdegis = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(degistir));  
              List<Object> arrayLines = new ArrayList<Object>();  
              Object contents;
            while ((contents = brdegis.readLine()) != null)  
              {  
              arrayLines.add(contents);  
              }  
              System.out.println(arrayLines + "\n");  
              String strLine;
              //Read File Line By Line
              while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
                 //Couldn't modify this part error is here :(
                  BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("c:/1_new.cfg"));
                    out.write(strLine);
                    out.close(); 
              }
                      in.close();
              degistir.close();
                }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
              System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
              }
              }
}
```

Comment: What is `function replace(arrayName,replaceTo, replaceWith)`? This will not compile in Java.

Comment: Well, first of all if you want to modify a file you'll need to write to it.  And you can't write to a `Reader` or `InputStream`, you need a `Writer` or `OutputStream`.

Comment: opps yes that function part is my problem i couldn't write that part for java that gathering strings from array and replacing it.

Comment: @Mark I took for now into buffer but i am planning lateron to take from buffer after it is changed and writing a new file.I didn't add that part yet.But it will work like that right ?

Answer (score 2):

You are opening the file for reading when you declare:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
```

If you know the entire file will fit in memory, I recommend doing the following :

- Open the file and read it's contents in memory into a giant string, then close the file.
- Apply your replace in one shot to the giant string.
- Open the file and write (e.g use a [BufferedWriter](http://www.javadb.com/write-to-file-using-bufferedwriter)) out the contents of the giant string, then close the file.

As a side note, your code as posted will not compile.  The quality of the responses you receive are correlated with the quality of the question asked.  Always include an [SCCE](http://sscce.org/) with your question to increase the chance of getting a precise answer to your question.

Comment: yes I also thought like that to open and buffer the file (by the way file is around 500kb) change the strings and then write as a new file but I didn't add that part now. I am now trying to search replace from array but couldn't manage it.I should also trim the array right ?

Comment: You're missing the point, whatever change you make to the array will not be reflected in the file.  You can change whatever you want to the array, and the file will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

can you elaborate the purpose of the program?

if it is a simple content replacement in a file.

then just read a line and store it in a string. then use string replace method for replacing a text in a string.

eg:

newStrog=oldString.replace(oldVlue,newValue);

Comment: so you mean that I should change all the bufferedfile into a string ? How can i do that ?